# Rest filter startswith(ContentTypeId,'0x0101') not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, odata

This is driving me crazy, but I think it's an issue on my sharepoint online.

Why the heck this is not working?

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items/?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,  '0x0101')
```

The craziest thing is that if I use `$filter=ContentTypeId eq  '0x0101.................'`, it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform a rest query using $filter and content type id field, you can do it like below:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,'0x0101')
```

Insert the internal column names in the $select to get the column names.

Comment: It was suppressed for the sake of moment. And, for sure it does not make any difference. but thank you anyway